# using states in a react-navigation without redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

as written in the react-navigation page:

*Warning: in the next major version of React Navigation, to be released in Fall 2018, we will no longer provide any information about how to integrate with Redux and it may cease to work.*

In the next version of react-navigation it could be hard to use redux with react-navigation.

My question is: what can I do to use states (and passing states between screens) in a react-navigation app without using redux?

Answer (score 0):

**For children of navigator**

react-navigation gives you an [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) HOC, so you can easily wrap the component inside it to access the navigation state and navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Why you integrate react navigation with redux?

For me, I want to be able to perform **navigation actions** from outside of my components(screens). Eg: Redux-saga. If we don't integrate, we can't navigate via redux-saga.

For a task like that we don't need to integrate **react-navigation and redux**. We just need to use [NavigationService](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).